# gcc doesn't give compile error when there is no foo() function

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

GCC doesn't give error 'undefined reference to `foo()' when foo()` is not defined and implemented.

GCC gives warning 'implicit declaration of function foo()'

When I execute the program, I meet the crash when `foo()` is called.

I would like gcc to give error.

Is there any gcc option except for `'-Werror-implicit-function-declaration'`?

or What is the problem?

Comment: 1.Show the code 2.Write specific queries in the question `TITLE`. ALso mention what language you are writing the code and the environment used for very specific answer to your query

Comment: I use `-std=c11 -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition` routinely, which certainly ensures that there's a full prototype declaration of all non-static functions before they're either defined or used (static function definitions can serve as their own prototype declarations).  You may be able to minimize the list of options a bit; there's also a `-Wold-style-declaration` option but that's essentially the same as `-Wstrict-prototypes`.

Comment: If the function `foo()` is called but not defined, you should get a linker error, not a run-time error — unless there's something weird going on like a global variable called `foo` somewhere in the source code (not in the file that calls `foo()`).  As @SantoshA says, we really need an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same idea — to know what you're doing.

Comment: The linker must give you an error when foo is indeed not implemented. (1) Look at the MAP file what module implements `foo`. (2) Look at the disassembly before executing the call to foo and dissamble the call destination.